# Fixed points in a complete lattice

Tags: order-theory, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a complete lattice, $\perp,\top$ be the least and the greatest element of $X$ and $f:X\to X$ is a monotonic function.

Tarski's fixed point theorem states that the set of fixed points forms a complete lattice.

If both $\top$ and $\perp$ are fixed points, is every element in $X$ a fixed point, i.e. $X=\{x\in X: f(x)=x\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the three-element chain, that is, $X=\{\bot,a,\top\}$, with $\bot<a<\top$.
Let $f:X\to X$ be given by $f(a)=\top$, and otherwise, $f(x)=x$.
It follows that $f$ is monotonic (indeed a lattice homomorphism), $\bot$ and $\top$ are fixed points but $a$ is not.